# GFCI 20 amp breaker pops....regular plug works

Tags: electrical

I have a dedicated 20 amp breaker in the panel box to a large 4 person whirlpool tub in my bathhroom.  I thought it would be great until I realized it puts out hundreds of gallons into my septic each time I use it. Therefore it sits pretty with no use over last 20 years...lol It works. ... but not worth blowing my septic field. So , I am remodeling my hall bath and bought a single 5 foot whirlpool tub that's manageable with my septic. I tore out old tub and it has a common wall with my large whirlpool tub. So, I piggy backed into the single 20 amp line as I wont use both tubs at same time ever. The new electric socket works with regular plug and no problems.  However, I figured electrical code probably calls for a GFCI socket since it's near water. So I sprung for a 20 amp GFCI socket and it trips when I plug anything in to test it. Wondering why it would trip and the regular socket works no problem?
Thanks,
Joules

[image][image][image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Exactly how is the breaker shared between the two tubs, and where is the outlet? (A diagram would be very helpful.)

Comment: Is there anything attached to the LOAD terminals on the GFCI?

Comment: I tapped into the electric box of the large whirlpool tub and spliced 12-2 wire .in to the 14-2 wire just before the switch to continue curcuit..

Comment: Then ran it 5 ft over to new box where I can plug in small whirlpool tub.

Comment: A regular plug works fine... no tripping of 20 amp

Comment: No tripping of 20 amp box breaker

Comment: I could just leave regular plug in...but...when I sell house... inspector may flag it with no GFCI at small whirlpool

Comment: The add on line is the end of the line...nothing else attached.

Comment: Of course...I am amateur...but attached white to white...black to black...and grounded.

Comment: Wondering if I got wrong 20 amp 125 VAC  60 Hz from Lowes.... or could it be 12-2 wire?

Comment: Tub drains are **gray water**.  Gray water doesn't need to go to septic. You could reuse it for in-lawn bubble irrigation or other purposes.  Once the tub is installed, how will you access this GFCI+receptacle to reset it? Is the tub actually cord-and-plug-connected?

Comment: It has opening  on front panel of tub...thinking aboi

Comment: Thinking about rerouting to drywell also...but have to RIP out some sheetrock

Comment: https://www.homedepot.com/p/American-Standard-EverClean-60-in-x-32-in-Right-Drain-Whirlpool-Tub-in-White-2425LC-RHO-020/100479052

Comment: One thing that is different about this 20 amp breaker  in the panel box dedicated line to the whirlpool is the breaker ihas it's on test button on it... could it be that its competing....and doesn't need GFCI?  Since it is dedicated?

Comment: I just added pic of the dedicated breaker in the panel box....I did not see a GFCI on the original 4 person whirlpool tub...probably since it's only appliance on that line and it was wired direct to switch box of the main 4 person tub.....that is where I tapped in to connect the secondary tub....will try to add pic of that.....so maybe when I added GFCI plug to secondary whirlpool....it eaa competing and tripped right away....or is the GFCI bad or wrong type?

Comment: Are you saying the GFCI socket in question is wired to a circuit already protected by a GFCI breaker?

Comment: Yes...it may be...look at pic of panel box breaker....it has it's own test red button..and that was dedicated to main whirlpool 4 person tub....then I piggied in and ran it 5 feet to secondary whirlpool tub....plug works great...but when replace it with GFCI...it pops right away

Comment: The second picture is air switch I tapped into without messing with the on and off of main 4 person tub...and ran out line to next door whirlpool tub....3 rd pic is inside air switch before I tapped in...I drilled hole to the right to run it out...you can see the out line in pic 2

Comment: What sort of cable did you use for the wire run from the place you made the tap to the new receptacle location?

Comment: @threephaseeel  I believe it's in the second photo, kinda looks like wet location cable, properly strain relieved and everything.

Comment: @Harper -- ah, I was having trouble telling what it was in the photo -- was half thinking it was cordage although the strain relief clamp looked pretty good.  If it's UF though, then cool cool, looks like he just needs to get past the "two GFCIs bickering somehow" problem

Comment: 12-2 line used as piggy back

Comment: Since it was dedicated line...I think the main breaker in panel with red test button was all that was needed and done by the original electrician 29 years ago when house was built.  The new outlet works fine with regular plug...I put on heavy high voltage spot light that draws lot of power and plugged in for 3 hours on and outlet was not hot or did not trip the 20 amp po ahel breaker. I wont be using both tubs at once on 20 amp unless I get drains rerouted to my dry well....dont want to blow my septic field with all that water.  I swear the 4 person tub takes 400 -500 gallons to fill it.

Answer (score 2):

### You don't need another GFCI, just put a regular receptacle here

The breaker's a GFCI already (between the TEST button, and 680.71 requiring GFCI protection for the existing tub), so you don't need *another* GFCI device to add to the confusion.  Simply put a regular 20A receptacle in with a "GFCI Protected" label on the faceplate, and you should be fine provided the GFCI breaker trips when you push its "TEST" button.